# Why is my ExportAsFixedFormat not working?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

A few days ago this macro succesfully protected all sheets and saved a copy of the workbook in PDF in the same folder adress where the excel file was placed.

Today i try to run the macro and when it comes to the PDF step it shows the message

> Run-time error 5: 
>   Invalid procedure call or argument

How can i fix it?

Thank you all

```
Sub pdf()
'
' pdf Macro
'

'

     Dim pwd1 As String, pwd2 As String
    pwd1 = InputBox("Please Enter the password")
    If pwd1 = "" Then Exit Sub
    pwd2 = InputBox("Please re-enter the password")

    If pwd2 = "" Then Exit Sub

     'Check if both the passwords are identical
    If InStr(1, pwd2, pwd1, 0) = 0 Or _
    InStr(1, pwd1, pwd2, 0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You entered different passwords. No action taken"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Protect Password:=pwd1
    Next

    MsgBox "All sheets Protected."
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a newly created (and not yet saved) workbook? What is the result of `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name`?

Comment: You are using `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` interchangeably. May not be affecting this particular code piece, but be consistent and know which one you mean. They are not the same thing. `ActiveWorkbook` should almost never be used. If you need to reference a specific book that is not the one running code, set it to a variable explicitly.

Comment: FYI your logic for verifying whether `pwd1` and `pwd2` are the same could be simplified to a much more obvious `If pwd1 <> pwd2 Then` logic. Unclear why one would need to enter the password twice though.

Comment: Most likely cause is `ActiveWorkbook` being some unsaved workbook, causing an invalid filename as @BigBen identified. We need to know which workbook you actually intend to export from though: `ThisWorkbook` is your VBA host document (the workbook that contains the VBA code); `ActiveWorkbook` is whatever workbook happens to be active when the instruction is executed. Note that unqualified, `Worksheets` implicitly refers to the `ActiveWorkbook`.... unless that code is written in the code-behind module for `ThisWorkbook`. Which is it?